# Non-static method requires a target docusign

Tags: docusignapi

I am using the following code to create the envelope on the existing template and I get the error "Non-static method requires a target". Is something I am doing wron here?

jQuery.ajax({

```
    url: "https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/<acountid>/envelopes",

            type: "post",
    headers: {
        "Accept": "application/json",
        "X-DocuSign-Authentication":"<DocuSignCredentials><Username>xxxxxx</Username><Password>xxxxxxx</Password><IntegratorKey>xxxxxxxx</IntegratorKey></DocuSignCredentials>",
        "Content-Length":"162100",
        "Content-Type":"application/json",
        "Content-Disposition":"form-data",
        "body":[{
            "status" : "sent",
            "emailSubject": "Test Pre-fill Tabs", 
            "emailBlurb":"test",  
                "status": "sent",
            "templateId": "xxxxxx-xxx-xxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxx",
            "templateRoles": 
        [{ 
        "roleName": "Supervisor",
        "name" :  "Test", 
        "email" : "Test@test.com",
        "recipientId" : "1"
        }],
        "envelopeIdStamping":"false"
        }]
        }   

    }).done(function( data ) a
    {
        console.log( "Success :");

    })
    .fail(function(msg,res)
    {
        console.log("error:");
    });
```

"{\r\n  \"errorCode\": \"UNSPECIFIED_ERROR\",\r\n  \"message\": \"Non-static method requires a target.\"\r\n}"

Answer (score 0):

This code using old auth, please consider using modern and more secure oauth. You can read about how to get a token using JWT here - https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/authentication/oauth2-jsonwebtoken

Also, consider updating to our latest API v2.1 from v2.0